# Exception loading CEFSHARP.CORE.DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7-x64, cefsharp

On **some** of our machines, we get an exception when trying to start CefBrowser from WPF code. I have been trying to troubleshoot this, but cannot really understand what goes wrong. The machines are all Win7 running 64-bit OS.

Below, I have captured a trace using "Dependency Walker" running the "CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.exe". (I apologize for the formatting, I don't know how to improve it.)

It starts out, then turns into an appcrash with the standard text "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

So - does anyone know what to do next? I can't really guess!

### Logfile from depends

```
> Loaded "RPCRTREMOTE.DLL" at address 0x000007FEFDCE0000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x000007FEFDCE0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "RPCRTREMOTE.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x000007FEFDCE0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "RPCRTREMOTE.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryExW("f:\public\dsu\debug\CefSharp.Core.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE80DDB40.
Loaded "CEFSHARP.CORE.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE2DA0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Unloaded "CEFSHARP.CORE.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE2DA0000.
LoadLibraryExW("f:\public\dsu\debug\CefSharp.Core.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
GetProcAddress(0x0000000077300000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "LCIDToLocaleName") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE80FDCE7 and returned 0x0000000077308680.
GetProcAddress(0x0000000077300000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "GetLocaleInfoEx") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE80FDCE7 and returned 0x00000000773035E0.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\en-US\mscorrc.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE) called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE81652C4.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\en-US\mscorrc.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE) returned NULL. Error: The system cannot find the file specified (2).
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\en\mscorrc.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE) called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE81652C4.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\en\mscorrc.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE) returned NULL. Error: The system cannot find the file specified (2).
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorrc.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE) called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE81652C4.
Mapped "MSCORRC.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x0000000000590001.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorrc.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE) returned 0x0000000000590001.
GetProcAddress(0x0000000077300000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "LocaleNameToLCID") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE80FDCE7 and returned 0x0000000077304FA0.
GetProcAddress(0x0000000077300000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "GetUserDefaultLocaleName") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE8202730 and returned 0x000000007734BB80.
GetProcAddress(0x0000000077300000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "GetUserPreferredUILanguages") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE82026F5 and returned 0x000000007734BB70.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\VERSION.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE80DDB40.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\VERSION.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
LoadLibraryExA("VERSION.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE81226AC.
Loaded "VERSION.DLL" at address 0x000007FEFCE30000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x000007FEFCE30000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "VERSION.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x000007FEFCE30000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "VERSION.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryExA("VERSION.dll", 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000) returned 0x000007FEFCE30000.
GetProcAddress(0x000007FEFCE30000 [VERSION.DLL], "GetFileVersionInfoSizeW") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE80E8131 and returned 0x000007FEFCE315FC.
LoadLibraryExW("CEFSHARP.MINIMALEXAMPLE.WPF.EXE", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "VERSION.DLL" at address 0x000007FEFCE31523.
...
Mapped "CEFSHARP.MINIMALEXAMPLE.WPF.EXE" as a data file into memory at address 0x000000013F400000.
LoadLibraryExW("f:\public\dsu\debug\CEFSHARP.MINIMALEXAMPLE.WPF.EXE", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x000000013F400000.
GetProcAddress(0x0000000077300000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "GetThreadErrorMode") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE84A9C64 and returned 0x0000000077365620.
GetProcAddress(0x0000000077300000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "SetThreadErrorMode") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE84A9C77 and returned 0x0000000077365660.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE816BC48.
Loaded "DIASYMREADER.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE2C90000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x000007FEE2C90000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "DIASYMREADER.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x000007FEE2C90000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x0000000000000000) in "DIASYMREADER.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned 0x000007FEE2C90000.
GetProcAddress(0x000007FEE2C90000 [DIASYMREADER.DLL], "DllGetClassObject") called from "CLR.DLL" at address 0x000007FEE816BC79 and returned 0x000007FEE2CA090C.
Second chance exception 0xE0434352 (Unknown) occurred in "KERNELBASE.DLL" at address 0x000007FEFE03AAAD.
Exited "CEFSHARP.MINIMALEXAMPLE.WPF.EXE" (process 0x18D4) with code -532462766 (0xE0434352).
```

Comment: You forgot to copy a DLL that cefsharp needs.  Probably the CRT, it tends to be available by accident.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see your program searching for the DLL and not finding it.  If it is the CRT then it will have a name like msvcr100.dll

Comment: ProcMon showed that two MSVC-files were missing: msvcp110.dll AND msvcr110.dll.  After copying these files to the output, it works. Big thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`CefSharp` is built using `VC++ 2012 Update 4`. Make note there a variants for `x86` and `x64`, so depending on your application make sure they match.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

When troubleshooting `CefSharp` some places to start are

- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions
- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/NuGet/Readme.txt#L16

Answer (score 1):

For anybody still looking for a solution to this issue, Please the simplest thing to do is to download and install Visual C++ 2012 if you are using CefSharp from Version 55 downwards, and Visual C++ 2013 if you are using CefSharp version 57. Please ensure to install the VC++ build (x86 or x64) depending on your application target chitecture (build). This took me a day and half to realise.

Have a look at this: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies

Comment: If you explain the context of that link, even just copy and pasting the relevant stuff, it'll be more useful in case that link ever changes :)

Comment: Version 43 was the last to use VS 2012, newer branches use 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by installing the following redistributable:
[image: Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Redistributable]

Visual Studio C++ 2015 **14.24.28127**, it contains core functionality from the library that is essential.